# Algorithm to get a point in a diagonal segment

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, logic

Look at this image(*sorry, I just have paint brush at my works' machine*):

[image]

There you see **two black rectangles**, one major and one minor, inside the major. Consider they are `div`s. **The red dots** are the center point of each one(top and left).

The **green rectangle** is a psychical(not draw on screen) boundary that symmetricly embraces the major reactangle, and it's calculated by JavaScript.

The **blue line** is the diagonal line segment of those two red dots.

I already have all positions of the above objects calculated on JavaScript.

The **yellow dot** is the point **I want to get**. It have to be on the diagonal line of the red dots but at the boundary(green line). It can't be out or inside it.

I have created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDH7q/) with my algorithm. As you can see that the yellow point is outside the green boundaries. It have to be in the diagonal segment **and** over the green line limitation.

Any help with this algorithm?

Comment: The algorithm currently ignores the green box altogether. Consider the equation of the line formed by the two centers you calculated. Then consider the equation of the vertical line left side of the green box, and the equation of the horizontal line top side (these are obviously trivial, y=0 or x=0 if the green left/top are the coordinate system axes). Using standard Algebra, you can find which one intersects the centers-line you determined and the coordinates of the intersection.

Comment: @mbratch sorry man, your answer seems to be easy but I can't imagine what to do in my code to comply with it.

Comment: NP. Looks like Sacho saved me the trouble of spelling out the equations in his answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More about slope: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/linear-equations-and-inequalitie/slope-and-intercepts/v/slope-of-a-line

You can use the point-slope formula to find points on a line(in order to find the one that will intersect the green top line):

```
(x1, y1) - one of the red points
(x2, y2) - another of the red points
(x, y) - the green point
slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) 
y - y1 = slope * (x - x1)
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to Imre Kerr:

Now, you already have either the point's y(if your line intersects the top green line), or the point's x(if it intersects the left green line). From this, you could find the other coordinate. A sample that assumes you're intersecting the top line (http://jsfiddle.net/BGSacho/TDH7q/6/).

Comment: Is it ever possible that the green box is tall enough (or, said another way, the major box is far enough away from the top of the green box) that the diagonal intersects the left side rather than the top?

Comment: Thank you so much man. I would vote your answer up ten times if I could for such nice answer.

Comment: @mbratch: That could happen. You'd know if you tried to solve for x and the result came out to less than the left of the green box. Then it's just a simple matter of solving for y instead, with x being constant.

Comment: @ImreKerr and whats the alg for solving for y ?

Comment: y = slope * (x - x1) + y1. Just reorder the equation.

Comment: @ImreKerr If not too much to ask, can you provide the equations for intersect the right and bottom side of the green lines? I'm a algebra lammer.